# C++ Creating a vector of function pointers inside a map

Tags: c++

So I have this class which is supposed to allow any other class to link their member functions to be called when an event happens (i.e a class could have one function linked to an arrow key press and a separate function linked to the spacebar), and I'm attempting to do this using a map, like so:

```
std::unordered_map<SDL_Event, std::vector<void(*)(void)>> Callbacks;
```

However this is giving this error:

```
C2280   'std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

The rest of the error information isn't helping since it points to a blank function in the definition for unordered_map (line 132):

```
unordered_map()
    : _Mybase(key_compare(), allocator_type())
    {   // construct empty map from defaults
    }
```

From what I'm able to understand the problem is that the unordered_map is trying to perform a hash on an empty function pointer for some reason and it's failing for obvious reasons.

I'm completely stuck as to what I can do as a solution to this that wouldn't involve writing my own version of a map, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: In order to use SDL_Event as a key to an unordered_map, it must be hashable and comparable. - I suspect it is not hashable, and maybe not comparable. Try using an ordinary map.

Comment: @NeilButterworth SDL_Event is not comparable, as you said. Since an ordinary map orders it's keys, it isn't possible to use an SDL_Event as a key.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty heavy hint you should not  be doing this mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use SDL_Event as key type for a std::map (ordered) you should provide your custom "less than" function that tells how to order two SDL_Event.

In order to use SDL_Event as key type for a std::unordered_map you should provide your custom "equal" function that tells how to differentiate two SDL_Event and you should provide your custom hash function that tells how to compute a hash value from a SDL_Event, this hash value should be equal for two SDL_Event that are equals according to your equal function, you can use std::hash applyed and combined to some fields of the SDL_Event structure.

The simpler way in to use a map with less than operator for SDL_Event :

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <SDL/SDL_events.h>

using namespace std;

inline bool operator<(const SDL_KeyboardEvent& lhs,
                      const SDL_KeyboardEvent& rhs)
{
    return lhs.keysym.sym < rhs.keysym.sym;
}

inline bool is_keyevent(const SDL_Event& ev)
{
    return ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN || ev.type == SDL_KEYUP;
}

inline bool operator<(const SDL_Event& lhs, const SDL_Event& rhs)
{
    return lhs.type < rhs.type ||
           lhs.type == rhs.type && is_keyevent(lhs) && lhs.key < rhs.key;
}

map<SDL_Event, vector<void(*)(void)>> Callbacks;
```

Note that the less than operator in this example provide two different entries for KEYDOWN and KEYUP.

Comment: @user2883136 It might resolve the compilation error, but I don't think it does what you want.

Comment: @user2883136 Is there a reason you don't want to use `SDL_EventType` as a map key?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, if I use SDL_EventType I can get when *a* key is pressed down, but there's no real way for me to differentiate between the different keys that are being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

> this class which is supposed to allow any other class to link their member functions to be called when an event happens

In addition to the event type, `SDL_Event` contains a lot of information that you don't need, such a timestamp of when the event happened.

Since the only thing you need is the event type, you should use `SDL_EventType` enum as a key:

```
std::unordered_map<SDL_EventType, std::vector<void(*)(void)>> Callbacks;
```

Since it's a simple enum, you don't need to define a custom comparator for it.